# Retrieve ProfilePasswordPolicy via API

Tags: soap-api, soap

The ProfilePasswordPolicy API returns the incorrect number of profiles. The count of Profiles in SF UI is 95 and this API returns the 83 profiles only.
Is there anything that I am missing?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no changes are made for the Profile's Password Policies, then there's no [ProfilePasswordPolicy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm) for it.

> Represents a profile’s password policies. Profile password policies
> **override org-wide password policies for that profile**’s users

Checking in the UI, you'll see what is displayed is identical to the *Organization's* Password Policies.

[SecuritySettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm) has the org-wide `passwordPolicies` those unchanged profiles are using.

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Security</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

Example of `SecuritySettings`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SecuritySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <passwordPolicies>
        <complexity>NoRestriction</complexity>
        <expiration>Never</expiration>
        <historyRestriction>0</historyRestriction>
        <lockoutInterval>FifteenMinutes</lockoutInterval>
        <maxLoginAttempts>TenAttempts</maxLoginAttempts>
        <minimumPasswordLength>5</minimumPasswordLength>
        <minimumPasswordLifetime>false</minimumPasswordLifetime>
        <obscureSecretAnswer>false</obscureSecretAnswer>
        <questionRestriction>DoesNotContainPassword</questionRestriction>
    </passwordPolicies>
    <sessionSettings>
    ...
    </sessionSettings>
    <singleSignOnSettings>
    ...
    </singleSignOnSettings>
</SecuritySettings>
```

Comment: Thanks after I made changes in password policies of default profiles, those profiles are reflected in the API response. Thank you very much :)

Comment: My one more question is pending https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/366926/104972  I would be most grateful if you could take a look at it.